# Unipotent upper triangular matrices with integer entries is Zariski dense

Tags: solution-verification, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $N$ be the group of matrices $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & z \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$, let $\Gamma$ be the subgroup of $N$ with $z \in \mathbb{Z}$.
I wish to show that $\Gamma$ is Zariski dense in $N$.
Polynomials in $\mathcal{O}[N]$ can be regarded as polynomials on $\mathbb{C}$, as there is a bijection between $N$ and $\mathbb{C}$. Thus if $f \in \mathcal{O}[N]$ vanishes on $\Gamma$, then by the fundamental theorem of algebra $f$ must vanish on $N$, so $\mathcal{O}[N] = \mathcal{O}[\Gamma]$ (the ideal that we quotient $\mathcal{O}[GL(2, \mathbb{C})]$ by is the same). Thus $N = \overline{\Gamma}$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But rather that just a bijection, you should check that there exists an isomorphism of algebraic variety between $N$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

Another way of seeing it: the Zariski closure of a set $X$ is the intersection of all $Z(f)$, for $f$ vanishing on $X$.

So $\bar{\Gamma} \supseteq N$.